# Compile cuda-toolkit to work with nvidia-driver-460

Tags: nvidia, cuda

nvidia driver v460 is compatible with cuda toolkit 11.2, i have installed cuda-toolkit 11.2 but when i do nvcc --version i get:

vcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

So it actually is 10.1 and that version is not compatible with nvidea 460 driver

I think this is why i this error when i do "nvidia-smi --version"
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Comment: Did you try this link https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html